# Pay attention when I speak - who am I?

Tags: riddle

Hark! Pay attention when I speak
And make way, or grave results may follow
My mirror image will tell you  who I am
Chase me, and you'll be considered the lowest of the low

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> an ambulance.

Hark! Pay attention when I speak

> Ambulances sound their sirens to draw attention when they're on the way to an emergency.

And make way, or grave results may follow

> If you don't let an ambulance through traffic, it will be delayed and the person it's trying to get to could die.

My mirror image will tell you who I am

> Ambulances have AMBULANCE printed backwards on their fronts, so that people looking in their rear-view mirrors can more easily recognise them.

Chase me, and you'll be considered the lowest of the low

> "Ambulance-chaser" is slang for a lawyer who rushes to accident scenes to convince the victim to employ them. They're generally considered to be predatory.

Comment: For some reason, reading "the lowest of the low" made me think of the Doppler effect.

Comment: I've always thought the mirrored-name on the front was pretty pointless.  They are completely recognizable without having to read the text, and obviously emergency vehicles that make loud noises and flashing lights, so I doubt there's anyone who wouldn't figure it out and get out of the way just because the text was backwards.  (And those who wouldn't are jerks who aren't likely to do so in any case.)

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Donald Trump

Because:

Hark! Pay attention when I speak
And make way, or grave results may follow

> Donald Trump has a huge ego and craves being paid attention to. He is known as a germaphobe, so you'd better make way when he passes by, or he may subject you to his typical insults and bullying behavior.

My mirror image will tell you who I am

> You see his image on TV (a flat, reflective surface like a mirror), where he is constantly reminding you of who he is and how great and smart he is.

Chase me, and you'll be considered the lowest of the low

> He consistently derides and insults all the other Republican presidential candidates for daring to chase him as the leading contender for the nomination.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> An ambulance?

Because,

> When you hear an ambulance you have to pay attention to see if you need to get out of the way and people might die if you block them. Ambulances have ambulance written on it mirrored so people can read through their rear view mirrors. Chasing an ambulance (to get through trafic) is usually frowned upon

Comment: On mobile, will format better later

Answer (score -1):

Its your Name cuz you pay attention when some one calls your name.

Comment: That doesn't fit any of the other lines.